# Finding the upper bound of a function of complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Considering $ |z|<\frac12 $. I am interested in finding the least upper bound of the function

$$
\left|\frac{z-2}{z^2+2iz-3}\right|
$$

**My attempt:** To find the required upper bound I have to find the least upper bound of the numerator and the greatest lower bound of the denominator. So I used the inqualities...
$ ||z_1|-|z_2||\le |z_1\pm z_2|\le |z_1|+|z_2| $

It's easy to find the least upper bound for the numerator as $ |z-2|\le |z|+2\lt{5\over 2} $.
but for the denominator, $ |z^2+2iz-3|\ge ||z|^2+2|z||- 3| $. From here I am not sure how to use the fact that $|z|\lt {1\over 2}$.

Comment: "*The* upper bound"? Do you mean the *lowest* upper bound, or *an* upper bound?

Comment: Well, the book only mentions upper bound, so I think it could be any but at the same time it says :'the' upper bound, so I am not sure myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|z^{2}+2iz-3| \geq 3-|z^{2}+2iz|\geq 3-|z|^{2}-2|z| >3-\frac  14-1=\frac  7  4$.

Comment: 'the upper bound' has no meaning.

Comment: The supemum will be attained when $|z|=\frac 1 2$. Write $z=\frac 1  2e^{i\theta}$ and try to get a  better bound than mine.

Comment: It was fault my side. Your answer is correct thank you!

Comment: @geetha290km I am sorry for asking so many question but I am again stuck. If I solve a similar question by your approach, the question begin when $|z|=2$ find the least upper bound of $$ \left|\frac {1}{z^4-4z^2+3}\right|$$ so $|z^4-4z^2+3|\ge |3-|z|^4-4|z|^2|=29 $ so the least upper bound should be $\frac {1}{29}$ but if I solve it by factorizing the denominator I get $|(z^2-3)(z^2-1)|\ge 3$ hence the upper bound is $\frac 13$. Can you help which is best to use? I don't want to leave any doubt uncleared, kindly help.